# Is there a difference between Assembly.ExportedTypes and Assembly.GetExportedTypes()

Tags: c#, .net, clr, .net-assembly

The .NET Assembly class contains a method ([GetExportedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexportedtypes.aspx)()) and a property ([ExportedTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.exportedtypes.aspx)).

The documentation for these seems identical ("Returns a collection of all public visible types in the assembly"). Is there any difference between these ? or is this something related to historical reasons with the Assembly class's API ?

Comment: Looks same but seems `ExportedTypes` property is new in .net 4.5

Comment: It is documented to be available in Store apps whereas GetExportedTypes is not.  Didn't quite pan out that way I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking into .NET sources using ILSpy returns following `ExportedTypes` implementation:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<Type> ExportedTypes
{
    get
    {
        return this.GetExportedTypes();
    }
}
```

However, classes that inherits `Assembly` class can implement the property differently, so you  probably shouldn't rely on `GetExportedTypes()` and `ExportedTypes` doing exactly the same thing.